# How do I stop the FirefoxCP process from preventing sleep on macOS?

Tags: macos, battery, sleep-wake, power

If I open my activity monitor and show the 'preventing sleep' column I notice that I have five process called `FirefoxCP Web Content` and one of those has the preventing sleep set to true.

How can I make my computer sleep when I ask it to?

Things I've tried

- disabled all add ons

I run macOS Ventura 13.3

How can I make my computer sleep when I ask it to?

Comment: They're likely to be for pages that intentionally keep the machine awake - radio stations etc do that.

Comment: is there a way to override this at all, it seems really crazy that macs don't sleep for so many reasons and don't provide any warnings that they won't sleep.

Comment: Close the tabs preventing sleep. The Mac isn't deciding to do this all by itself, it's being told to.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Tetsujin . I don't know which tabs are the ones preventing sleep, also it seems a crazy to close all my apps down and then sleep, I might as well just shut my whole mac down. The reason I want to sleep my computer is to preserve the state of the applications open but that doesn't seem to work. Maybe the mac spec for the sleep command is a faulty; it should at least warn you that it won't sleep and your battery will run out if you're not careful.

Comment: Most apps these days return to the same state after a reboot (with the notable exception of Adobe apps which insist you save or discard first)

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestions @Tetsujin but for me terminal windows don't return, windows are opened on different pages and of course it takes a few minutes if you have a lot open.  It is also very easy to lose work like this and not really practical to do so every time you are not using your computer for a few hours.  All that is really needed is a warning when the sleep button is pressed. I have opened a thread on apple as I think the sleep specification is flawed
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252402793

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have gotten a tip from a Mozilla developer, which is to do this:

- Go to `about:config` in the address bar of Firefox (you will get a warning, so you should accept and continue).
- Enter `media.video-wakelock` into the search bar.
- Set the value of `media.video-wakelock` to false.

This will stop Firefox from preventing sleep when videos are showing (which can include ads, apparently). It does mean that the Mac can go to sleep when videos are playing in the browser, but... small price to pay, I would say.

Comment: I came back here to check, because this is a good answer, and I had completely forgotten that it is my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to stop it, however, I manually initiate a sleep on the mac and override 'Preventing Sleep' applications from the command line:

`pmset sleepnow`

(you may find something in `man pmset` that can alter the settings, I performed a quick look but couldn't find anything)